# Inconsistencies in values from mallinfo and ps

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to identify a huge memory growth in a linux application which runs around 20-25 threads. From one of those threads I dump the memory stats using the system call mallinfo . It shows the total allocated space as 1005025904 (uordblks). However, the top command shows a value of 8GB as total memory and 7GB as resident memory. Can some one explain this inconsistency?

Following is the full stat from mallinfo:

```
Total non-mmapped bytes (arena):       1005035520
 # of free chunks (ordblks):            2
 # of free fastbin blocks (smblks):     0
 # of mapped regions (hblks):           43
Bytes in mapped regions (hblkhd):      15769600
Max. total allocated space (usmblks):  0
Free bytes held in fastbins (fsmblks): 0
Total allocated space (uordblks):      1005025904
Total free space (fordblks):           9616
Topmost releasable block (keepcost):   9584
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is mallinfo gives the stats of the main arena. To find details of all arena's you have to use the system call malloc_stats.